# How to open a .txt.enc file?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have a .txt.enc file. It is an output of openssl enc. I need to open it. 
When I try to open it in Emacs, the first some characters(also known characters) are : 'Salted__C' . 
how can I understand that which decryption method such as '-aes-256-cbc' or '-cast5-cbc' I should use to open it?

Comment: AFAIK, [ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) is an important property of a good encryption scheme. Having the ciphertext only, you're _supposed_ to not be able to know how it was encrypted. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What Adnan says about [ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) is correct, this can be a [hard problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used), the only clue you have is "`Salted__`" string which is how OpenSSL distinguishes [salted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and unsalted encrypted data.

Assuming the file was encrypted with a password (or key/IV pair) that you have, you will have to try every every method:

```
ciphers=$(openssl enc -h 2>&1 | nawk '/^Cipher/ {n++; next}; (n) {print}')
password=xyzzy

for cc in $ciphers; do
    openssl enc -d $cc -pass pass:$password \
        -in myfile.txt.enc -out outfile$cc.txt  2> /dev/null
    rc=$?
    # check for non-zero exit, or output file size not > zero bytes 
    if [ $rc -ne 0 -o ! -s outfile$cc.txt ]; then
        echo "Failed with $cc"
    else 
        echo "Possible success with $cc"
    fi
done
```

(There are some duplicate ciphers due to name aliases, e.g .`aes-128` = `aes-128-cbc`.)

Now you'll see the [next](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/computer-decryption-algorithms-and-knowing-the-solution) [problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10804/verify-the-password-of-an-encrypted-file-without-waiting-for-complete-decryption), with many algorithms you can decrypt ciphertext with a bad password and [not know if the algorithm and/or password were correct](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/detecting-end-state-of-decryption-process-with-unknown-key).

There are a number of methods to determine if a password was correct and a decryption was successful (e.g. via checksum, integrity (e.g. [with HMAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812232/c-sharp-aes-rijndael-detecting-invalid-passwords)), padding (e.g. [with PKCS#5](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html#NOTES)) or other [expected structure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22763/password-checking-in-the-context-of-symmetric-encryption), or known "left over" state), though sometimes not being able to tell is in fact a [feature](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/automated-encryption-detection).

Comment: Your bash-fu is strong, whats this bit do? `rc=$? if [ $rc -ne 0 -o ! -s outfile$cc.txt ];`

Comment: Save the exit status `$?` in `rc` (not strictly required here, just habit), then test for non-zero exit, or (`-o`) that the output file size is not greater than 0 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I'm trying your code with some common passwords, hoping to get some results. So far, not so good!